# Does transformZ improve plain-image rendering in web browsers?

Tags: css, performance, web, browser, web-performance

Helloo!

I am working on a web application that shows something like a facebook newsfeed, and tends to contain atleast one image per update in the newsfeed. So as the user scrolls down to new updates, the images within these updates get rendered.

I have been exploring ways to improve the scroll performance and hence looking into ways to improve the rendering of images. I [read a bit](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) about the `transform: translateZ(0)` CSS property that indicates to the browser to push the processing over to the GPU. And it seems this tends to result in better performance since GPU is computationally stronger.

My question is whether we can use this trick to render just plain images, without any animation/transformation? Would it result in GPU handling the rendering of the images and hence result in a better scroll performance on an image heavy site, by leaving the CPU available for other work?

Much appreciate any inputs!